# right click not appear at right place

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a map app where when right clicked on a google map, it shows some options.

the problem is right click is not appearing at right place.

How can I resolve this?

I tried positioning it by using position absolute.

Also tried, below Jquery code,

```
 $( ".map-context-menu" ).click(function() {

      var styleProps = $( this ).css([
        "Ra", "latLng", "pixel"
      ]);
      $.each( styleProps, function( prop, value ) {
        html.push( prop + ": " + value );
      });

    });
```

this is my html

```
`<div class="map-context-menu" ng-show="contextMenuActive">

                <div class="map-context-menu-item" >
                    Item 1
                </div>
                <div class="map-context-menu-item">
                    Item 2
                </div>
            </div>
`
```

Comment: have you tried with offset?

Comment: no. I haven't. let me give it a try

Comment: @Medda86 I tried didn't worked.

Comment: "I tried, didn't work" is not helpful. What did you try? What was the outcome? What was the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('map-context-menu')) {
        $('#contextMenu').css({
            left: e.pageX + 'px',
            top: e.pageY + 'px'
        }).show().fadeIn(500);
    }
    return false;
});
```

This will automatically position the `#contextMenu` where you have right-clicked within `map-context-menu`

> **e.stopPropagation()**

This will stop method from overcrowding the DOM. Ensures the the previous `context menu` is destroyed before another is created. For example, say if you do 2 right clicks in a row at different locations...instead of 2 spawning, the 1st will hide before the 2nd is created

> **e.preventDefault()**

Will prevent the browser default context menu from being shown. For example, whenever you right click on anywhere in a web page, a default context menu will appear that is created by the browser. This line prevents that and will display your custom created one instead

**N.B:** Please change `#contextMenu` to the ID or class of your custom context menu you created. For example: *(the HTML)*

```
 <ul id="contextMenu">
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
 </ul>
```

I have added this CSS code to my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fr92kvz8/2/) and everything seems to be working fine. *(The styling can be modified, it's the `position: fixed` and `display: none` that are crucial to this working)*

**CSS**

```
#contextMenu {
    background-color: red;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    font-size: 20px;

    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 150px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px grey;
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for helping. few questions though. 

firstly, why are you 

`e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation(); 
`

I mean, what are we trying to stop here?

thanks again.

Comment: and also its not working. I am not getting any errors though

Comment: Thanks a mil for that. No luck still. No errors.

Also I have edited my question, just to show you my related html. thanks again.

Comment: Not a problem. I have edited my question again supplying an example jsFiddle with some useful CSS code as well

Comment: Recently updated the jsFiddle to more suit your HTML. *N.B: This solution is pure jQuery and does not require any Angular)*